# "Shuffle images" in French

Tags: vocabulaire, anglais

For an button caption I am looking for a short French translation of the term “shuffle images”. This button would order a set of images randomly.

A couple of attempts:

> randomiser l'ordre
>
> rendre aléatoire
>
> mélanger des images

What would be the best translation?

Answer (score 5):

It is difficult to find a single verb translating shuffle, *randomiser* is ugly, *réorganiser de manière aléatoire l'ordre des images* is technically correct but too verbose<sup>1</sup> so, assuming the space allowed to the caption is sparse, the best choice is ***mélanger*** les images.

There is also the verb *battre* which is common with cards (*battre les cartes* / shuffle the cards) but it doesn't work with *images*.

<sup>1</sup><sub>*Tri aléatoire* has rightly been suggested. It might look an oxymoron but the images can actually be "randomly sorted" by a program, for example according to a randomly chosen key.</sub>

Comment: “Trier aléatoirement” could be another option.

Comment: @Stéphane Giménez : un tri n'est-il pas par définition fait en fonction d'un critère, et donc jamais totalement aléatoire ? Upvote cependant car "mélanger" me semble être la meilleure traduction de "Shuffle" dans ce contexte

Comment: @LaurentS. Le critère de tri peut très bien être une clef associée à chaque élément à trier et choisie avec une fonction aléatoire...

Comment: Pourquoi mettre des maths là où il n'y en a pas ? Vous utilisez une clé pour trier des photos vous ?

Comment: And by the way, although “rendre aléatoire l'ordre des images” seems fine as configuration parameter, it can't really be used for a one time action.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Oui, tous les tris s'effectue en fonction d'un critère qu'on peut appeler une clef. Un tri consiste à ordonner des éléments en fonction d'une ou plusieurs valeurs qui est associée à chacun d'entre eux. Pour des images, ce peut être la taille, la date de création, le thème, la luminosité, la couleur dominante, le nom du photographe, la focale utilisée etc. Pour ordonner de façon aléatoire des images, le plus simple est d'affecter une clef aléatoire à chaque image, puis à trier numériquement les images en fonction de cette clef.

Comment: Moi quand je trie des photos je garde celles qui me plaisent et je les organise comme il me semble bon… *trier* est un verbe qui existait avant que l'informatique apparaisse… Sinon, quelle clé pour trier les déchets ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Les "clefs" que tu utilises pour trier tes photos sont d'une part ton avis personnel "me plait"/"ne me plait pas" et d'autre part quelque chose de plus difficile à modéliser nommé "comme j'ai envie de les organiser". Pour trier les déchets, la clef (ou critère si tu préfères) de tri est la matière et le type d'objet, le verre dans le conteneur vert, les épluchures au compost, etc. La question porte sur un bouton affiché par un programme informatique qui va afficher des images dans un ordre aléatoire. Difficile d'ignorer les mathématiques et l'algorithmique dans ce cas précis.

Comment: Je crois qu'il va falloir faire du tri dans les commentaires…

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez et prendre la clef des champs...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep it concise:

- Images au hasard
- Images aléatoires

I think it is best to avoid the verb here for concision.

Answer (score 1):

1.As I think that button captions do not necessarily have to be very concise,

2.as I believe that sometimes they are not and

3.as I'd rather have as much information as possible in a caption, specially considering the emptiness of the screen around a multitude of  captions that are brief but at times quite opaque,

I wouldn't mind reading your caption  as

"**nouvel ordre aléatoire**"

or even

"**nouvel ordre aléatoire**

**des images**".

Answer (score 0):

If the button is below a set of images, I don't think that it is necessary to mention image in the caption.

I therefore suggest to focus on the action, which then depends on what you do exactly with your images:

If you keep the same set of images but modify their order on the screen, I would use

```
ordre/mélange aléatoire
```

e.g. images 1,2,3,4,5 --> 5,2,3,4,1

If you have more image than the number of images shown, I would use

```
tirage aléatoire
```

or, because "tirage" is often random (e.g. le tirage de la loterie),

```
nouveau tirage
```

e.g. images 10,25,1,99,12 --> 88,24,6,35,5

If you like to mention images on the button, you could use:

```
mélanger les images
```

in the first case (reordering) and

```
tirer des nouvelles images
```

in the second case (random sampling)